# In a Boost Converter, where is most of the heat dissipated?

Tags: power-supply, power, heatsink

In a circuit like this:

[image: 12V to 24V Boot Converter]

I am for now assuming that a lot of the head will be dissipated by the Diode, and hence I am preparing the PCB to include a heat sink for it just in case. But what about the inductor and the switching IC U2? And the MOSFET?

Any tips on PCB design to dissipate a lot of the heat that will come out of this circuit at max load?

Comment: You can connect ground to a large ground plane to dissipate heat.  In a lot of designs you will see a MOSFET laid on it's side with the heat sink soldered to the ground plane for this same purpose.

Comment: That is bad practice. Copper and FR4 do not bend under heat the same way. Excessive heat will delaminate the copper from the FR4, or worse, crack traces. These problems are a bear to troubleshoot because they're heat induced and very intermittent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hop on over to the [TI page](http://www.ti.com/product/lm3478&lpos=Middle_Container&lid=Alternative_Devices) for this chip, and fire up the Webench.

[image: Webench for lm3478]

That will tell you a lot about the power supply. Click on the Op Vals icon at the top, and it will list loads of useful variables.

[image: Webench Op Vars for LM3478]

Here you can see the power dissipation for the MOSFET, Diode and IC. It looks like the MOSFET dissipates the most power, and so will need the most heatsinking. Try it yourself, and put in the correct values for input and output voltages and output current that you'll be using.

Comment: Wot?, No inductor losses?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - This is only an excerpt from the list. Inductor losses are probably further down.

Comment: Even if the inductor had the greatest losses (which happens, quite a lot of times), I don't know if a heatsink would be appropiate... :)

Comment: How would you dissipate the heat from the inductor?

Comment: A fan is probably your best bet.